# "Bite me", What does it mean?

Tags: idioms, expressions

"Bite me" is an expression used in a lot of TV series. Does it mean "leave me alone" or something else? Example: Someone tells Penny that she is stupid. She answers, "bite me". Is it an old expression?

Comment: There's a thorough explanation of this phrase on our sister site here: [ELU Meaning of "bite me"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27753)

Answer (score 5):

It's a very informal usage of the idiom in AmE.

> [bite me (very informal)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Bite+me!) - *used to say to someone that they have made you feel angry or embarrassed.*

I don't think it's an old expression. So, if you find someone telling *bite me*, they are annoyed and about to burst!

If you look at [this video (uploaded a year back)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0dLFCbwqMUI), it talks about the slang *bite me* (The video just talks about the term in Hindi).

Another (vulgar) definition is here on the [Urban Dictionary.](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bite%20me)